# Не могу верно определить разницу во времени

Tags: java

Нужно расчитать разницу (в днях) между двумя точками во времени. Не получается. Нужна помощь.

```
package util;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class CountOfLivedDays
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        LocalDate born = LocalDate.of(2000, 9, 29);
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        Period period = Period.between(born, now);
        System.out.println(period.get(ChronoUnit.DAYS)) // 22
        System.out.println(period.getYears()); // 16
        System.out.println(period.getMonths()); // 2
        System.out.println(period.getDays()); // 22
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30833631/1646082) или [офф. доки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html). Чтобы определить разницу в днях надо использовать класс [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) и в вашем случае будет что-то такое:

```
LocalDate born = LocalDate.of(2000, 9, 29);
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(born, now));
```

Вывод:

> 5927